# Why rbind throws a warning

Tags: r

This is related to [Are there more elegant ways to transform ragged data into a tidy dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102617/are-there-more-elegant-ways-to-transform-ragged-data-into-a-tidy-dataframe)

Why following code is not working:

```
events = structure(list(date = structure(c(-714974, -714579, -717835), class = "Date"), 
    days = c(1, 6, 0.5), name = c("Intro to stats", "Stats Winter school", 
    "TidyR tools"), topics = c("probability|R", "R|regression|ggplot", 
    "tidyR|dplyr")), .Names = c("date", "days", "name", "topics"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

> newdf <- data.frame(topic=character(), days=character())
> for(i in 1:length(events$topics)){
+ xx = unlist(strsplit(events$topics[i],'\\|'))
+ for(j in 1:length(xx)){
+ yy = c(xx[j], events$days[i]/length(xx))
+ print(yy)
+ newdf=rbind(newdf, yy)
+ }
+ }
[1] "probability" "0.5"        
[1] "R"   "0.5"
[1] "R" "2"
[1] "regression" "2"         
[1] "ggplot" "2"     
[1] "tidyR" "0.25" 
[1] "dplyr" "0.25" 
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> newdf
  X.probability. X.0.5.
1    probability    0.5
2           <NA>    0.5
3           <NA>   <NA>
4           <NA>   <NA>
5           <NA>   <NA>
6           <NA>   <NA>
7           <NA>   <NA>
> 
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, NA ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, NA,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, 1L,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, NA,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, 1L,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
6: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, NA,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
7: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, 1L,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
8: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, NA,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
9: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, 1L,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
10: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, NA,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
11: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = structure(c(1L, 1L,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
>
```

yy is okay but rbind is not working. Where is the error and how can it be corrected? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try:

```
newdf <- data.frame(topic=character(), daysPerTopic=character(), stringsAsFactors=F)
for(i in 1:length(events$topics)){
xx = unlist(strsplit(events$topics[i],'\\|'))
for(j in 1:length(xx)){
yy = data.frame(topic=xx[j], daysPerTopic=events$days[i]/length(xx), stringsAsFactors=F)
newdf <- rbind(newdf, yy) 
 }
 }

 newdf
#        topic daysPerTopic
# 1 probability         0.50
# 2           R         0.50
# 3           R         2.00
# 4  regression         2.00
# 5      ggplot         2.00
# 6       tidyR         0.25
# 7       dplyr         0.25
```

Or

```
 op <- options(stringsAsFactors=F)  #set to F

 #Your code
 newdf <- data.frame(topic=character(), days=character())
 for(i in 1:length(events$topics)){
 xx = unlist(strsplit(events$topics[i],'\\|'))
 for(j in 1:length(xx)){
yy = c(xx[j], events$days[i]/length(xx))
print(yy)
newdf=rbind(newdf, yy)
 }
 }

 newdf
#  X.probability. X.0.5.
# 1    probability    0.5
# 2              R    0.5
# 3              R      2
# 4     regression      2
# 5         ggplot      2
# 6          tidyR   0.25
# 7          dplyr   0.25

 options(op) #et back to default
```

Comment: I did'nt realize that both arguments of rbind should be data frames.

Comment: @rnso, they are not. Just be careful when you are dealing with factors, that's all.

Comment: OK. stringsAsFactors=F is the key issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Did you even try to debug your `for` loop? For example, by adding `print(class(yy))` `print(str(newdf))` you would see that after first iteration both `newdf` vectors become factors.

```
# [1] "probability" "0.5"        
# [1] "character"
# 'data.frame':  0 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ topic: Factor w/ 0 levels: 
#   $ days : Factor w/ 0 levels: 
#   NULL
# [1] "R"   "0.5"
# [1] "character"
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ X.probability.: Factor w/ 1 level "probability": 1
# $ X.0.5.        : Factor w/ 1 level "0.5": 1
# NULL
# [1] "R" "2"
# [1] "character"
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ X.probability.: Factor w/ 1 level "probability": 1 NA
# $ X.0.5.        : Factor w/ 1 level "0.5": 1 1

...
```

You would say "but I defined them as `character`". True, but if you'll read `rbind` documentation, you will see that

> For cbind (rbind), vectors of zero length (including NULL) are ignored
>   unless the result would have zero rows (columns), for S compatibility.
>   (Zero-extent matrices do not occur in S3 and are not ignored in R.)

Another property of `rbind` is that it inherits it's properties from `data.frame` while one of them is `stringsAsFactors == TRUE`

What happened here could be easily illustrated in a dummy example, consider

```
temp <- data.frame(A = letters[1:3])
str(temp)
## 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
## $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3

temp$A[3] <- "d"
## Warning message:
## In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = c(1L, 2L, NA)) :
##   invalid factor level, NA generated

temp$A
## [1] a    b    <NA>
## Levels: a b c
```

You can see two things here:

- `data.frame` automatically converted `character` class to factors
- When trying to parse a new level to `factor` vector it converts it into `NA` and throws the exact error you were receiving

As mentioned by @akrun, setting to `options(stringsAsFactors=F)` will solve your problem

Comment: Yes, yes, mmhmm, yes, yes, and I agree.  +1

Comment: I did try print(..) lines in  code for debug but did not write all that here.

Answer (score 3):

Set
    options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
and your code should work as expected. The reason for the warnings and NA's in the result is because of the implicit conversion to factors and the type mismatch between newdf columns and yy, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1640729/1541036.

For a cleaner way of achieving the same result, here's a group by solution using data.table

```
library(data.table)
events <- as.data.table(events)
events2 <- events[, list(topic=unlist(strsplit(topics, '|', fixed=TRUE))), by=c("date", "days", "name")]
events2[, probability := days / .N, by=name]
```